# how to prove that the following limit doesn't exist when puting L=3 using epsilon-delta definition?

Tags: calculus, epsilon-delta

I have $$\lim_{x\to 0}\sqrt{4-x}=2$$ and what I did is: let $$ |\sqrt{4-x}-2|<\epsilon $$
then $$-(\epsilon+2)^2+4<x<-(-\epsilon+2)^2+4$$
so I took $\delta=min{[-(\epsilon+2)^2+4,-(-\epsilon+2)^2+4)}]$ therefore proving the limit.
But I don't understand when this would be wrong. For example if instead of using the limit as 2 I used limit as 3 then the proof would be almost the same but wrong. So my question is, in which part would be wrong and why? That's what I don't understand

Comment: You shouldn't just say "Let $|\sqrt{4-x}-2|<\epsilon$". esp. if $\varepsilon>0$ is arbitrarily small, and you do not put the $2$ there, it might not be possible to have e.g. $|\sqrt{4-x}-3|<\epsilon$ if $\epsilon<1$.

Comment: I do not understand the question. The limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\sqrt{4-x}$ there exists and its values is $2$.

Comment: I forgot about stating that $\epsilon>0$ and such. But why the -2 doesn't go there? The definition is $|f(x)-L|=\epsilon$

Comment: Sorry, I will edit the title

Comment: "For example if instead of using the limit as 2 I used limit as 3" Can you be more precise in what you mean by this please?

Comment: I meant that if instead of building a proof with the limit = 2 I used limit = 3 then how could I know if the proof is wrong. Because I would write something similar for that limit and the limit wouldn't exist in the first place

Comment: Recall the definition of a limit $L$ of a function $f$ at $x=a.$ We say $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)=L$ if for all $\epsilon>0,$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $0<|x-a|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon.$  Note $\epsilon>0$ is given to you. You need to find $\delta>0$ satisfying the above condition. In the case you want to disprove a limit, then you need to find an $\epsilon>0$ such that you can't find a $\delta>0$ satisfying the definition of the limit.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Recall the definition of a limit $L$ of a function $f$ at $x=a.$ We say $$\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)=L$$ if for all $\epsilon>0,$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $0<|x-a|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon.$
You want to disprove $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 2} \sqrt{4-x}=3.$$ What you need to do is pick a number $\epsilon>0$ such that there is **no** $\delta>0$ with the property that $0<|x-2|<\delta$ implies $|\sqrt{4-x}-3|<\epsilon.$

Alternatively, use the uniqueness property of limits: If $f$ has limit $L$ at $x=a,$ then $L$ is unique. That is, if $L_1,L_2$ are limits of $f$ at $x=a,$ then $L_1=L_2.$ Try proving this fact.

Then, based on this fact, can both $2$ and $3$ be limits of $\sqrt{4-x}$ at $x=2$ ?